# Find the Locus of The Circle Touching Two Circles

Tags: geometry, analytic-geometry, circles

*Here circle 'A' and 'B' have the radii $a$ and $b$ respectively. 'C' is a circle belonging to the mentioned family of circles. How to solve this problem?[image]* 
**(circle 'C' is drawn just for clarification)**

Answer (score 4):

**Hint.**  Assume you have two fixed points $F_1$ and $F_2$ in the plane and a fixed positive number $d > |F_1F_2|$. What is the geometric locus of all points $X$ in the plane with the property that $|F_1X| + |XF_2| = d \,$? Do you have two such points on your picture and a number $d$ that you can use to form such a locus?

Comment: So....required locus is the ellipse whose foci are c1 and c2.

Comment: And d=a is this ok? @Futurologist

Comment: @SujanDutta actually $d=a+b$

Comment: @dxiv Futurologist is correct. You cannot draw arbitrarily large circles, $C$, since $C$ must be internally tangent to $A$.

Comment: @dxiv Probably the problem is related specifically to the picture, where circle $B$ is inside circle $A$ and touches it. Then the family of $C$ circles are contained in $B$, so they cannot move farther and farther away in this case. Maybe you are referring to the case when $A$ is tangent to $B$ form the outside?

Comment: @Hrhm & Futurologist You are both right, I misread the drawing (and for externally tangent circles the locus is a hyperbola). It would have been better if the *internally* tangent assumption were explicitly spelled out in the OP. I'll delete my previous comment shortly.

Comment: @dxiv I figured that much. And indeed, the post is a bit unclear... plus when one is a hurry, one doesn't look closely at posts :D...